# Showing that the hypothesis that $m (E) <\infty $ is essential in the Egoroff's theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence

In Egoroff theorem, the hypothesis that $ m (E) <\infty $ is essential. Construct an example of measurable functions $ f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb {R} $ that converge to the null function with the following property: if $ F \subset \mathbb{R} $ and $ m (R \backslash F) <\infty $ then $ \{f_n \}$ **not converges *uniformly* on $ F $**

I have not idea how to do this! I'm thinking for days but to no avail! I'm terrible with examples ...

Comment: $f_n=\chi_{[n,n+1]}$.

Comment: @DavidMitra
I will try to show that it satisfies all of these properties of the exercise. It is not obvious to me.

Comment: Even easier, take $f_n=\chi_{[n,\infty)}$.

Comment: @DavidMitra
But... you do not need to fix a set $F$ such that all works?

Comment: Yes. Fix $F$ and show that for any $n$ there is an $x\in F$ and $N\ge n$ with $f_N(x)=1$. This will show that $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly to $0$ on $F$.

Comment: I'm confused by the size of this $ F $ appears that for $m^*(R\backslash F)<\infty $ it has to be VERY large and it is catching me.

Comment: Note that it's so large that for any $n$, the set $F\cap [n,\infty)$ has positive measure.

Comment: @DavidMitra Can you see my answer? Do you think I need any more arguments besides that $F$ is large to ensure the existence of the $x$ (and the $N$) or just say it? Can you help me again? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where
                        $$
      f_n(x)=
      \left \{
      \begin{array}{ll}
      1 & \textrm{ if } x\in[n,\infty) \\ 
      0 & \textrm{ if } x\not\in[n,\infty)
      \end{array}
      \right.
      $$
Let $F\subset \mathbb{R}$,  $m(\mathbb{R}\backslash F)<\infty$ a closed set.

For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ exists $x\in F$ and $N\geq n$ such that $f_N(x)=1$. This works because F is very large and always lets us find these elements (in $[N,\infty)$)